# 74HC688 magnitude comparator and enable pin

Tags: arduino, ttl

I'm using a 74HC688 8-bit magnitude comparator ([datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT688_CNV.pdf)) with Arduino. My question is **how to generate active LOW E (enable) signal with Arduino?** Is there another possibility (I want to enable the 688 chip)? Currently, I have the enable pin connected to ground. Is that the correct solution or do I need a resistor between enable and ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 74HC688 permanently enabled, you should connect the enable pin directly to ground.  If you want the Arduino to control the enable pin, connect the enable pin directly to an Aduino output pin.